# Menu superfish Multilanguage Drupal7

Tags: drupal-7, block, multilingual, superfish

I developpe a multilangual website for the first time and I meet some problem with superfish menu. I have two menu, one in french and an other in english.

Superfish block display the french menu entierly, but when I switch to the english menu, the english menu displays only entry with neutral language.

I want a full menu in both languages. I had follow unsuccesfully this tutorial http://renaudjoubert.com/en/article/setting-multilingual-menus-d7.

Can someone help me ? :)

thanks